# Why does changing the values of a shape key affect the whole model?

Tags: shape-keys

I am working with Manuel Bastioni humanoids. They use shape keys for facial expressions. The shape keys of the girl in the middle have gone completely out of wack, that is, when changing the values, the whole body deforms. I cannot find the solution. Can anybody help please?

Thank you!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9p4lgii00swiju/COMPLEETconcept04.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Probably you separated the humanoid by material or something and then finalised.  You'll have to start all over again, finalise and then separate. Should work. Happened to me once.

Comment: Even if humanoid is finalised, and you separate parts of the object. Shape keys cease to work and appear deformed. Try looking at website for assistance

Comment: Instead of commenting, edit your answer to include all the solution.